# Sorting xml nodes

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Let's say I have the following xml:

```
  <editions>
    <edition language="English">en.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="French">fr.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="Vietnamese">vi.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="Turkish">tr.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="Spanish">es.wiktionary.org</edition>
  </editions>
```

I can grab all 'editions' in Xpath using:

```
//editions/edition
```

This can be tested here: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. Does XPath support a way to sort results? For example, I would like to sort descendingly by the language attribute, so the correct 'answer' would be:

```
Element='<edition language="Vietnamese">vi.wiktionary.org</edition>'
Element='<edition language="Turkish">tr.wiktionary.org</edition>'
Element='<edition language="French">fr.wiktionary.org</edition>'
Element='<edition language="Spanish">es.wiktionary.org</edition>'
Element='<edition language="English">en.wiktionary.org</edition>'
```

Note I have tagged this question with python, but any language can be used here. In python I would do it outside XPath (because I don't know how) doing something like:

```
nodes = sorted(etree.fromstring(s).xpath('//edition'), 
    key=lambda node: node.attrib['language'], reverse=True)
nodes[0].text
# 'vi.wiktionary.org'
```

Comment: If you can use xpath 3.1, this may work `reverse(sort(//edition, (), function($edition) {$edition//@language}))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ''' <editions>
    <edition language="English">en.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="French">fr.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="Vietnamese">vi.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="Turkish">tr.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="Zoo">zz.wiktionary.org</edition>
    <edition language="Spanish">es.wiktionary.org</edition>
  </editions>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
editions = root.findall('.//edition')
sorted_editions = sorted(editions, key=lambda e: e.attrib['language'])
for edition in sorted_editions:
    print(edition.attrib['language'])
```

Comment: no I mean within xpath itself. This is just what I already have above, no?

Comment: Ohhh. Got it. I am not aware of a way to sort via xpath.